# Are there any other stories about Darth Zannah other than the Bane Trilogy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-bane

I've read the Darth Bane trilogy several times. One of the things I really liked about the books is the backstory of "Rain"/Zannah and being able to adapt her force skills to accommodate her much smaller size against a very powerful and larger Darth Bane. I would like to know more about her in the post-Bane era.

Are there any other EU/Legends stories that explore Darth Zannah further other than briefly mentioning her in passing?

Answer (score 3):

### Jedi vs Sith

[image: JediVsSith]

The comic Jedi vs Sith contains the story of Rain & her brothers living on Somov Rit during the war between the Jedi and the Sith, and how Darth Bane met and recruited her following the destruction of the Sith and most of the Jedi following the use of a Thought Bomb by the Sith.

Comment: But isn't the Bane Trilogy basically a retcon of JvS? What aspects of Zannah are different between the comic and the trilogy? Is there more info in JvS on Zannah's reign after Bane dies?